# How to implement the downloading of JavaScript variables such as a string, array in the form of a file on click of a button on Internet Explorer 8+?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a JavaScript string which I want to be downloaded when the user clicks a particular button.

I have got it to work on Firefox and Chrome using a data URI and creating a new anchor element which links to this data URI.

However, I found out that this way of doing it is not supported on IE due to security reasons.

Can someone tell me how can I download a file on clicking a button so that it works on IE using Vanilla JavaScript?

Thanks for your help.

Kevin

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: `<a href="path/to/your/file">Link</a>` doesn't work? What type of file? What else have you tried?

Comment: `var fileContents = "Welcome";  
var link = document.createElement("a");  
dataURI = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(fileContents);  
link.setAttribute('href',dataURI);  
link['download'] = "welcome.txt";  
document.body.appendChild(link);  
link.click();  
document.body.removeChild(link);  `